# How Do I Get Text Info (cell M) to add to date info (Cell R) and create the new date (Cell S) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to calculate a new date based on information from two other cells, one of which is text.

The text indicates how often repeat visits should take place (there are only 4 options: 'Every 4 weeks', 'Every 8 weeks', 'Every 12 weeks', 'Once a year')

I want this information to then be added so column R (last visit date) to create Column S (next visit date)

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried IF formulas and IFS formulas but I just can't get it to work - I have tried to convert the text into days (for example, 'Every 4 weeks' = 28 days).

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to include an image in your question. Can you please upload it to imgur.com and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1399290/edit) to include a link to it?

Answer (score 2):

A nested IF will work.

`=IF(Q2="Every 4 Weeks",R2+28, IF(Q2="Every 8 Weeks",R2+56,IF(Q2="Every 12 Weeks",R2+84,IF(Q2="Once a year",R2+365,"Invalid Repeat Interval"))))`

So basically:

- if the repeat matches "Every 4 Weeks" then add 28 to the last visit date;
- ELSE if the repeat matches "Every 8 weeks" then add 56 days to the last visit date;
- ELSE if the repeat matches "Every 12 weeks" then add 84 days to the last visit date;
- ELSE if the repeat matches "Once a year" then add 365 days to the last visit date;
- If nothing matches print "Invalid Repeat Interval" in the cell.

[image: See Image]